# how to add seed method in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run code-first migrations with Entity Framework. I enable, add, and update. When I update, it says it runs the seed method and there are no errors, but when I look at the data in the tables, there isn't any.

Here is my Seeder:

```
public static class Seeder
{
    public static void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Props.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.PropId,
            new Prop() { PropName = "sharpie" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "coin" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "playing cards" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "coffee mug" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "phone" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "keys" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "sunglasses" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "headphones" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "ring" },
            new Prop() { PropName = "lighter" }
            );

        context.Theories.AddOrUpdate(
            t => t.TheoryId,
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 0,
                TheoryName = "Production",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it appear out of nowhere!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 1,
                TheoryName = "Vanish",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it vanish into thin air!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 2,
                TheoryName = "Transportation",
                TheoryDescription = "Make it vanish, and then reappear somewhere impossible!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 3,
                TheoryName = "Transformation", // This uses TWO props
                TheoryDescription = "Cause one of these items to change into the other item!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 4,
                TheoryName = "Multiplication",
                TheoryDescription = "Magically duplicate this item again and again!"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 5,
                TheoryName = "Penetration", // This uses TWO props
                TheoryDescription = "Cause the two items to inexplicably pass through each other"
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 6,
                TheoryName = "Restoration",
                TheoryDescription = "Destroy the item in some way. Restore it."
            },
            new Theory()
            {
               // TheoryId = 7,
                TheoryName = "Levitation",
                TheoryDescription = "Make the item float in mid-air!"
            });

        //////////////////////////////////////////// The following seeds user data

        // ApplicationUser table seeder
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        RoleStore<Role> roleStore = new RoleStore<Role>(context);
        RoleManager<Role> roleManager = new RoleManager<Role>(roleStore);

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            roleManager.Create(new Role { Name = "Admin" });

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
            roleManager.Create(new Role { Name = "User" });

        IdentityResult result = null; // Sets the result to null. Used for error checking.

        /////////// Admin (1)
        ApplicationUser admin1 = userManager.FindByName("MagicRawb");

        if (admin1 == null)
        {
            admin1 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Rob",
                LastName = "Greenwald",
                UserName = "magicrawb",
                Email = "magicrawb@test.com",
                Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(admin1, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(admin1.Id, "Admin"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        admin1 = userManager.FindByName("MagicRawb"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// Admin (2)
        ApplicationUser admin2 = userManager.FindByName("admin2");

        if (admin2 == null)
        {
            admin2 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Bekah",
                LastName = "Cellz",
                UserName = "admin2",
                Email = "admin2@test.com",
                Gender = Gender.Female
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(admin2, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(admin2.Id, "Admin"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        admin1 = userManager.FindByName("admin2"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// User (1)
        ApplicationUser user1 = userManager.FindByName("user1");

        if (user1 == null)
        {
            user1 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "Lance",
                LastName = "Burton",
                UserName = "user1",
                Email = "user1@test.com",
                Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(user1, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(user1.Id, "User"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        user1 = userManager.FindByName("user1"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        /////////// User (2)
        ApplicationUser user2 = userManager.FindByName("user2");

        if (user2 == null)
        {
            user2 = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = "David",
                LastName = "Stone",
                UserName = "user2",
                Email = "user2@test.com",
                Gender = Gender.Male
            };
        }

        result = userManager.Create(user2, "asdfasdf");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string error = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        userManager.AddToRole(user1.Id, "User"); // Add user1 to Admin role
        user2 = userManager.FindByName("user2"); // Assign user1 data to variable user1

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And here is my DbContext:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
public IDbSet<Prop> Props { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Theory> Theories { get; set; }
public IDbSet<NewTrick> NewTricks { get; set; }
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm glad to provide any info I might be missing.

Comment: You should tell EF to run your Seed method!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Seeder.Seed(context); in the configuration.cs file?

Comment: You can also add a Seed method to your initializer (instead of or in addition to the migration initializer). You can actually debug this code and see where it errors out. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a configuration class like

```
internal class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
          //seed code here
    }
}
```

and then have an initializer class like

```
public class MyInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>
{
}
```

and at the end set the initializer for your EF database in your application startup

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
```

Comment: Just did this and when I update-database I get:
Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.

Comment: this is a good sign that your seed method is running now. You should check the seed code to see where is the problem. The error is almost self-explanatory.

Comment: Cool. I honestly don't see where I'm inserting multiple entities with the same key. The objects keys are all their ID's and I'm not setting those. I DID for the theories, but commented them out so entity would do it automagically instead.

Comment: That's a whole new question. Ask it in new question please.

Answer (score 0):

You have added UserRole to UserManager twice using the following line of code `userManager.AddToRole(user1.Id, "User")` This might be the cause for the conflict.

To be exact copy the above code you posted, on a new file and look at line number 159 and 184.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that! I changed it and I'm still getting: "Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key."

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason. Put a break point, and try to debug the code.